# Why do I get an "Arrow type ... unkown" warning with this dot file?

Tags: warnings, graphviz, dot

When I process the following file with dot (version 2.38.0), I get a `Warning: Arrow type "fooo" unknown - ignoring`.

```
digraph {
  n1 [ label="ND 1" ];
  n5 [ label="ND 5" ];

  n12 [
    label=<
        <table>
         <tr>
           <td port='fooo'>FOOOOOO</td>
         </tr>
       </table>>
  ];

  n12:fooo -> n1;

  n5 -> n1 [arrowhead=invempty];

 {rank=same; n1 n12}

}
```

I am unable to figure out, why that is.

When I remove either the `n5 -> n1 [arrowhead=invempty];` or the `{rank=same; n1 n12}` statement, the warning goes away.

Can someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0):

It just doesn't like your `port='fooo'` attribute, as that is not a defined alternative for port.  Even though the documentation suggests that an ID is okay there, replacing `fooo` with `e` (from the list of available "compass point" options) gives a good result:

```
digraph {
  n1 [ label="ND 1" ];
  n5 [ label="ND 5" ];
  n12 [ label=<<table><tr><td port='e'>FOOOOOO</td></tr></table>> ];
  n12:e -> n1;
  n5 -> n1 [arrowhead="invempty"];
 {rank=same; n1 n12}
}
```

with no warnings of any kind.  This is puzzling because the documentations states that **port:':' ID [ ':' compass_pt ]** is valid, suggesting that compass point is optional but that ID is not.  Your example suggests otherwise.

Comment: Imho, this is a bug in the parser. If I place the `n12:fooo -> n1;` *after* the `n5 -> n1 [arrowhead=invempty];` or if add `[arrowhead=normal]` to `n12:fooo -> n1`, the warning goes away and the graph is rendered correctly.

Comment: I'd have to agree @RenéNyffenegger, for the syntax you tried conforms to the specification as outlined in the DOT language documentation.